# Proving Set is Connected and Complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, connectedness, complete-spaces

Problem 1. Let (C([0,1])) denote the space of continuous real-valued functions on
([0,1]) equipped with the distance
$$
d(f, g)=\sup _{x \in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|
$$
Let (X) be a subset of (C([0,1])) defined via
(X={f:[0,1] $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(0)=0 \text { and }|f(x)-f(y)| \leq|x-y|\}$
Show that (X) is connected and complete.

I have been having trouble understanding this question. In my "proof," I essentially said that since connected sets map to connected sets, then the set determined by $f(x)$ is connected. I have tried doing it by contradiction, but I am not getting anywhere.

Any clarification on what the problem actually wants would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Why all the parentheses? For example "Let \(C([0,1])\) denote the space of continuous real-valued functions on
\([0,1]\)..." should be "Let $C([0,1])$ denote the space of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]...$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not proving that $X$ is path-connected?

For $f,g\in X$ and $t\in[0,1]$, we are to show that $tf+(1-t)g\in X$.

Note that $(tf+(1-t)g)(0)=0$ and 
\begin{align*}
|(tf+(1-t)g)(x)-(tf+(1-t)g)(y)|&\leq t|f(x)-f(y)|+(1-t)|g(x)-g(y)|\\
&\leq t|x-y|+(1-t)|x-y|\\
&=|x-y|.
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm sorry, but I guess I don't even understand what the set $X$ is. How is $g$ related at all? Sorry -- I know about path connectedness, but I am not understanding where $g$ comes in.

Comment: The set $X$ is what you have written. The term $g$ is assumed to be there. We need to pick two elements from $X$, I called them $f,g$ and prove that their convex combination is in $X$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

Hints: Show that $X$ is a closed subset of $C[0,1]$. This implies that $X$ is complete.

Show that$f,g \in X$ implies that $tf+(1-t)g \in X$  for $0\leq t \leq 1$. This implies that $t \to tf+(1-t)g $ is a path connecting $f$ and $g$. Hence $X$ is connected.